# Straight-lines chart with dynamic data (currently using graphael lib)

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, raphael, graphael

I am trying to build a **dynamically** fed (data) **straight lines** chart. I built a prototype using [graphael.](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Line Charts</title>
  <script src="raphael.js"></script>
  <script src="g.raphael.js"></script>
  <script src="g.line.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  window.onload = function () {
    var r = Raphael("holder");
    var yAxisTags = ["A","B","C","D"];
    var xData = [
        [2000,2015],//hack line, transparent; used to specify the range of the axis
        [2008,2014],[2004,2005],[2009,2010],[2000,2007],[2000,2014],[2010,2012]
    ];
    var yData = [
        [1, 1],//y coordinates of hack line
        [0, 0],[1, 1],[1, 1],[2, 2],[3, 3],[0,0],
        [0, 0]//hack line, transparent.Used to be able to draw straight lines
    ];
    var colors =  [
      'transparent',//line 1
      'red','green','green','purple','turquoise','black',
      'transparent'];//'transparent' IS A MUST, a hack to make it have a straight line
    var options = {
        nostroke: false,
        gutter: 90,
        axis: "0 0 1 1",
        symbol: "circle",
        axisxstep:10,
        axisystep:3,
        colors: colors
    };
    var lines = r.linechart(100, 10, 700, 300,xData,yData,options);

    // AXIS (x and y) have values but do not drawn the lines
    lines.axis[0].attr([{stroke: false}]);
    lines.axis[1].attr([{stroke: false}]);

    // Thickness of symbols (ie dots)
    lines.symbols.attr({ r: 4 });

    // Animate dots on first load
    lines.animate({"stroke-width": 1}, 1000);//ALL lines,1000 is animation time

    // Set text for Y axis coordinates (instead of numbers)
    $.each(lines.axis[1].text.items, function(index, label) {
      this.attr("text", yAxisTags[index]);
    });
};
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="holder" style="width:50%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**And here is how it looks like:**
[image: graphael_line_chart]

So basically I want a **time related (jumps +2 years from point to point)** line chart graph with  **labels on Y-axis**, that is made by drawing straight lines  **and to which dynamic data is being fed**. The current code works with **this specific configuration only** but **once i start modifying the data, the display is not accurate anymore:**

- x-axis (time axis) gets buggy and time doesn't jump +2 years
- if there is a large difference in between two years (2 X coordinates), the line is drawn as a dot
- will have to modify **axisxstep** and **axisxstep** (don't understand how the logic behind these works to be honest)
- etc..

Is there a technique/hack around to make my desired line chart concept work with dynamic data using [graphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)? or it is not feasible with this library?

Comment: d3.js is certainly worth a look if no other specific replies and you get bogged down with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For anyone stuck with this same scenario:**

Since I am using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), I ended up using [angular-google-chart.](https://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart)

It is a directive wrapper around [google chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/); it is stable and straightforward to use.